# Swift: Convert Dictionary to String with Line Breaks

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift2

I have a dictionary of error objects and I want to concatenate the errorMessage property into a string with line breaks as separators for each item in the dictionary. The following code does the job however I'm sure there must be a more elegant way

```
var errorMessage = ""
var count = 1
for (_, error) in validator.errors {
    errorMessage += error.errorMessage + "\n"
    if count < validator.errors.count{
        errorMessage +=  "\n"             
    }
    count++
}
```

What's the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
let errorMessage = validator.errors.values.map({$0.errorMessage}).joinWithSeparator("\n")
```

should to the trick (not compiler checked, there may be typos but
you should get the idea).

- `validator.errors.values` gives (a sequence of) all dictionary values.
- `.map({$0.errorMessage})` maps each value `error` to `error.errorMessage`, the result is an array.
- `.joinWithSeparator("\n")` concatenates the array elements with
  interposing newline characters.

Comment: thanks, that got me down the right route but was giving a compiler error. This is what worked in the end: let errorMessage = validator.errors.map({"\($0.1.errorMessage)"}).joinWithSeparator("\n")  Does that seem right to you?

Comment: @ExoticChimp: Did you try `validator.errors.values.map`? Note the `values` which I added later. But your solution is almost identical and also correct.

Comment: actually sorry your solution also worked, i just can't copy and paste properly!!